# LINQ to SQL multiple left join query with subquery at join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, join, subquery

I have a SQL query that takes a subquery as a parameter for a left join.

```
SELECT tblfLeaseDetail.Lease_Detail_ID,
       tblfPayment.Payment_Date,
       tblfAuthorization.Authorized,
       tblvVendor.Vendor_Name,
       tblvCounty.County
  FROM tblfLeaseDetail
  LEFT
  JOIN tblfPayment
    ON tblfPayment.Lease_Detail_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.Lease_Detail_ID
   AND tblfPayment.Payment_ID =
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                 Payment_ID
            FROM tblfPayment
           WHERE tblfPayment.Lease_Detail_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.Lease_Detail_ID
           ORDER BY Payment_Date DESC
       )
    LEFT
  JOIN tblfAuthorization
    ON tblfAuthorization.Lease_Detail_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.Lease_Detail_ID
   AND tblfAuthorization.Authorization_ID =
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                 Authorization_ID
            FROM tblfAuthorization
           WHERE tblfAuthorization.Lease_Detail_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.Lease_Detail_ID
           ORDER BY Authorized_Date DESC
       )
    LEFT JOIN tblvVendor
    on tblvVendor.Vendor_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.Vendor_ID
    LEFT JOIN tblvCounty
    on tblvCounty.County_ID = tblfLeaseDetail.County_ID
```

I'm trying to convert it to LINQ. So far this is what I've done:

```
var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                             join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID into la
                             from jla in
                                 (from aj in leases.tblfAuthorizations
                                  where aj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby aj.Authorized_Date descending
                                  select aj.Authorization_ID).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join p in leases.tblfPayments on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals p.Lease_Detail_ID into lp
                             from jlp in 
                                 (from pj in leases.tblfPayments
                                  where pj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby pj.Payment_Date descending
                                  select pj.Payment_ID).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID into lv
                             from jlv in lv.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID into lc
                             from jlc in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new LeaseViewModel()
                             {
                                 Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID,                                     
                                 Vendor_Name = jlv.Vendor_Name,                                  
                                 County = jlc.County,
                                 Authorization = jla.Authorized,
                                 Payment_Date = jlp.Payment_Date
                             }).Distinct()
```

This returns me an error at *jla.Authorized* and *jlp.Payment_Date*:

**'int' does not contain a definition for 'Authorized' and no extension method 'Authorized' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found**

The same error goes for Payment_Date.

Why are jla and jlp being considered ints? How can I make this query work?

**EDIT:**

This is the final and working LINQ query:

```
var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                             join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID into la
                             from jla in la.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where jla.Authorization_ID == (from aj in leases.tblfAuthorizations
                                  where aj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby aj.Authorized_Date descending
                                  select aj.Authorization_ID).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
                             join p in leases.tblfPayments on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals p.Lease_Detail_ID into lp
                             from jlp in lp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                             where jlp.Payment_ID == (from pj in leases.tblfPayments
                                  where pj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby pj.Payment_Date descending
                                  select pj.Payment_ID).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
                             join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID into lv
                             from jlv in lv.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID into lc
                             from jlc in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new LeaseViewModel()
                             {
                                 Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID,
                                 Lease_ID = l.Lease_ID,
                                 XRef_Lease_ID = l.XRef_Lease_ID,
                                 Vendor_Name = jlv.Vendor_Name,
                                 Description = l.Description,
                                 County = jlc.County,
                                 Amount = l.Amount,
                                 Payment_Due_Date = l.Payment_Due_Date,
                                 Lease_Type = l.Lease_Type.ToString(),
                                 Location_ID = l.Location_ID,
                                 Active = l.Active,
                                 Expiration_Date = l.Expiration_Date,
                                 Authorization = jla.Authorized,
                                 Payment_Date = jlp.Payment_Date
                             }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Because in jla you selected `aj.Authorization_ID` which is an int.  Try changing to `select aj` instead.

Comment: Off topic but it wouldn't it be a lot easier to use a view?

Comment: When I try to use **aj** VS says it doesn't exist in the current context.When I try to use **la** VS says it doesn't contain a definition for Authorized.

Comment: I need the to select the IDs from Authorization and Payment tables, because without them I'll have multiple results for a same Lease_Detail_ID. Also, I still don't understand why jlv and jlc are range variables and jla and jlp are ints. Is this because of the type that my subquery is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are selecting Authorization_ID and Payment_ID which are of type int into jla and jlp respectively . Try the below query and let me know how it worked for you.

```
var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                             join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID into la
                             from jla in
                                 (from aj in leases.tblfAuthorizations
                                  where aj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby aj.Authorized_Date descending
                                  select aj).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join p in leases.tblfPayments on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals p.Lease_Detail_ID into lp
                             from jlp in 
                                 (from pj in leases.tblfPayments
                                  where pj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                  orderby pj.Payment_Date descending
                                  select pj).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID into lv
                             from jlv in lv.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID into lc
                             from jlc in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new LeaseViewModel()
                             {
                                 Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID,                                     
                                 Vendor_Name = jlv.Vendor_Name,                                  
                                 County = jlc.County,
                                 Authorization = jla.Authorized,
                                 Payment_Date = jlp.Payment_Date
                             }).Distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks Shoeb! That helped a lot! I edited the post with my final LINQ query, which is basically yours with a few changes. It's working now!